# My app can not create file in "appDataFolder" of google drive

Tags: java, android-studio, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

How can I create a file in google drive "appDataFolder"?

I created google developer console settings which is necessary for creating file and accessing "appDataFolder".

[google developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onb1b.png)

Android Studio output error messages as below.

```
W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
    {
      "code": 403,
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "global",
          "message": "The granted scopes do not allow use of the Application Data folder.",
          "reason": "insufficientScopes"
        }
      ],
      "message": "The granted scopes do not allow use of the Application Data folder."
    }
W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at com.example.test1.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:131)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Source code is

```
                        File body = new File();
                        body.setName(FILE_TITLE);//fileContent.getName());
                        body.setMimeType("text/plain");
                        body.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));

                        File file = service.files().create(body, content)
                                .setFields("id")
                                .execute();
```

If the following line is commented out in the source code, my app can create a file in google drive
top folder not "appDataFolder".

```
body.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
```

Android Studio 4.1.2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33VwP.png)

Best regards.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While from the looks of your developer console image you apear to have include a large number of scopes.  The issue here is not with your settings in google developer console but rather with the scopes you have authorized your user with.

When you run your application the user is asked to consent to your accessing some of their data, this is the scope of authorization for your application. It defines what the user has granted your application access to do.

If your code only requests read only access then and you try to write to it then your going to see an insufficientScopes error message.

You need to check what scope is required of the method you are using and then make sure when you authorize your user that you are requesting that scope.

My guess is you have something like this

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
```

YOu need to include this scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata` which is probably something like `DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA`

Remember once the scopes have been changed in your application you will need to reauthorize the user.  If your storing the consent then it needs to be removed in order to request authorization again.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid comment.

May I ask why do you think my code only requests read only access?
I intend that my app tries to write(create a file).

Comment: There are one EditText and two Buttons in my android app screen layout.
After pushing "Save" Button, the OAuth consent screen appears on my android terminal as you say.
The consent screen request me displaying, editing, creating, deleting all files on google drive.
And after I agree it, my app requests creating a file in the specific folder called as "appDataFolder" which is not visible to the owner of the google drive data.

Comment: But error has occured in spite of including ".../auth/drive.appdata" scope into the settings of consent screen of google developer console.

Comment: I am guessing that you are only requesting read only access because you have not include your authorization code where we can see what scopes you have requested.  Once you have changed the scope remember that you need to force a reauthorization of the user for it to pick up the change or your code is just going to be running off the old consent.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and letting me notice that there is an authorization code in other place in my source code which you can not see! And my app get to create a file on google drive appDataFolder!

Comment: "DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA" need to be included in onStart method as below.

Comment: credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE, DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA));

Comment: Thanks DaImTo and others who watch this question.

Comment: Happy i could help even though i don't know Android :)